# Dimensionality issue with Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, dimension

I thought this should be fairly simple, I really have no idea what went wrong, been trying for a week, gosh!! so ashamed of myself.

I define the following at Workspace:

```
I = [5 5.1 5.2 5.2];
V = [95 80 85 20];
```

I expect an output like this:

```
%// at t=0
arr=20

%// at t=1    
arr=30

%// at t=2
arr=40
```

When I run the simulation, what I got is:

```
%// at t=0
arr = 20, 0, 0, 0

%// at t=1
arr = 0, 10, 0, 0

%// at t=2
arr = 0, 0, 10, 0
```

There are few problems with this result:

1. I expect only one `arr` value at a particular time, but it came out four `arr` values at a time
2. I wonder why the `arr` never adds up to 30 and 40 etc

My system is as follow:

[image]

The codes are here:

[image]

I managed to get only one value at a time, but why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc? it keeps detecting that arr(count-1,1) is ALWAYS zero

Comment: arr = zeros(4,1) sets arr as an array. Then you change one value in it, so it returns an array length 4 with one value changed.

Comment: Thanks Simon, if I define arr = zeros(1,1) instead of arr = zeros(4,1),how could I retrieve the arr(1,1) value when the current value is in the arr(2,1)?

Comment: @user2563812: Please describe the intended output for the function, I don't know what you expect as a single output value.

Comment: Hi Daniel R, I expect something like this:
%// at t=0
arr=20

%// at t=1    
arr=30

%// at t=2
arr=40

Comment: I managed to get only one value at a time, but why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc? it keeps detecting that arr(count-1,1) is ALWAYS zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the final `end`, insert

```
scalar_value = arr(count,1);
```

and declare your function as

```
[arr, scalar_value] = fcn(signal,V,count)
```

This will get the value of interest (scalar_value) in the 4x1 vector `arr`, without disrupting the `arr` logic.

Comment: Thanks Macduff, I tried your approach, it did finally give me a single value at a particular time. Mind to explain why it is needed to overwrite the scalar?
Now, I got this output: 
%// at t=0
arr = 20

%// at t=1
arr = 10

%// at t=2
arr = 10
May I know, why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc?

Comment: Please, see my edit. Overwriting is not necessary - you may declare a second output as the scalar of interest.

Comment: Thanks Macduff for the explanation. I managed to get only one value at a time, but why the arr never adds up to 30 and 40 etc? it keeps detecting that  arr(count-1,1) is ALWAYS zero

Comment: You may want to insert `disp(count)` within you function to see wether count increases or not, and `disp(arr)`to see the evolution of arr.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I enable debugging and I am sure the count did increase from 1 to 2, 3 and so on. However, the  integ_signal(count,1) contains very weird value such as 0.3412 etc. I have no idea what went wrong in this simple code

Comment: Once you know that count increase by +1, you can be sure that `arr(count-1,1)` is always zero because `arr` is declared as zeros and only one of its value (arr(count,1)) is modified.

Comment: yeah only one of its value is modified but it is not the right value , i am wondering could it be a matter of sample and hold?

Comment: I run the codes in m file without any function, it did gives me correct value, 20, 30,40. but i dont know why when I combine all the blocks in Simulink, the value stays at 10 all the time